# No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC. So I have started with very simple MVC application. In this application, I am trying to submit login form but it is givivng below mentioned error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/My-project] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /profile/logon.jsp at line 8

    5: </head>
    6: <body>
    7: <h2>USER Login</h2>
    8: <form:form method="post" action="addlogon.jsp">
    9: 
    10:     <table>
    11:     <tr>


    Stacktrace:] with root cause
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:219)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:75)
        at org.apache.jsp.profile.logon_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(logon_jsp.java:110)
        at org.apache.jsp.profile.logon_jsp._jspService(logon_jsp.java:79)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1815)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Below is my code detail:

web.xml:

```
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.paradigamatic.marchent.web.controller" />
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/profile/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
```

Controller class:

```
    @Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class LogonController  {

    @RequestMapping(value="/profile/addlogon", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addlogon(@ModelAttribute("userlogon") UserLogon userlogon, BindingResult result){

        String user=userlogon.getUsername();
        String user1=userlogon.getPassword();
            return "redirect:logon.jsp";
        }

@RequestMapping(value="/profile/logon", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handalRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)
{

    System.out.println("I am in controller");
    return new ModelAndView("logon", "command", new UserLogon());

}
```

Please tell me why I am getting that exception? Any help will be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Gopal

Comment: First try to clean the server. If this does not help, then please post your web.xml and which version of tomcat do you use.

Comment: Added few code. Now can you please check.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a context load listener to your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>        
<param-value>/WEB-INF/yourApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The listener:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: But I don't need ApplicationContext.xml in my application till now. Also there there is one tutorial which is working fine on my machine. Below is the link: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/

Comment: It looks from the stack trace like it's the Spring JSP tag <form:form/> that's requiring the ContextLoaderListener. Did you just start using that tag library?

Comment: Same problem here. When I'm using Spring JSP Tag form I'm getting this error. Without it I am not getting any error. Please note that I have app-servlet.xml and ContextLoaderListener all set up in my application.

Answer (score 0):

what version of Spring MVC are you using? Check the stack trace with the source code. If you use Maven, your IDE should be able to link the stack trace lines with the jar source codes.